# Using agora.io in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, agora.io

This question might sound quite silly, but I need your help.
I have successfully implemented the agora.io live interactive streaming in flutter and is running fine. I wanted to know if I can implement this same feature in vue.js. I was trying to find any documentation but couldn't find any.
Can anyone help me find any documentation or at least a git repo which I can refer to.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Agora doesn't officially have any documentation for making a interactive streaming web app in Vue, it does have one for Group Video Calls at https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/OpenAgoraWeb-Vue.

Since video calls work almost the same as broadcasts, you can use the [OpenAgoraWeb](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/OpenAgoraWeb-Vue) repo link and tune it in a way to make it only one way streaming for audiences.

A sample interactive streaming web app for web using Vanilla JS: https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo.

You can also use this [Vanilla Sample](https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo) link to convert it into a VueJS application or you can use a combination of both.

You can also create it from scratch using the documentation at: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_web?platform=Web.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I have never checked the developer center.